# Why is repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions not sorting?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is what I am doing:

```
val rddkv = sc.parallelize(List(("k1",1),("k2",2),("k1",2),("k3",5),("k3",1)))
    //rddkv.collect
    //Array[(String, Int)] = Array((k1,1), (k2,2), (k1,2), (k3,5), (k3,1))

rddkv.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner(3,rddkv)).mapPartitionsWithIndex( (i,iter_p) => iter_p.map(x=>" index="+i+" value="+x)).collect
    //Array[String] = Array(" index=0 value=(k1,1)", " index=0 value=(k1,2)", " index=1 value=(k2,2)", " index=1 value=(k3,5)", " index=1 value=(k3,1)")
```

Notice that the values within the partitions aren't sorted. Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDD is actually sorted, you probably have misunderstood how the method [`OrderedRDDFunctions.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions) works. The method operates on a RDD of key-value pairs `(K,V)`, where `K` is the key and `V` is the value. It will repartition and then sort the data *by the key*.

Looking at the order of your output: `(k1,1), (k1,2), (k2,2), (k3,5), (k3,1)`, it is correctly sorted after the key.

If you simply want to sort the values, ignoring which partition they are in, you can simply do `rdd.sortBy(_._2)`.